# Accuracy Class and Full Scale

Tags: sensor, measurement, transducer, instrumentation

I am using this formula to calculate the class of an instrument:

\$\text{Accuracy Class} = \frac{\max{\text{(Absolute Error in Range of Measurement)}}}{\text{Full Scale Value}}\$

The question is, FSV is the full scale OUTPUT or INPUT value?

- In example, I have a preasure sensor with a full scale input of 100 kPa, the full scale output is 0.999 V and the max absolute error is 0.016261156.

  - The class of the instrument is 0.016261156 (using FSV=100kPa) or is 1.627743331 (using FSV=0.999)?
  - (the second one makes more sense to me, because it is an usual value and units of the quotient values cancels it self).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the FS output is 0.999V in and the maximum error in the output is 0.016V then the accuracy class is 1.6%.